# Mock a function before importing a module

Tags: python, airflow, pytest

I have an Airflow DAG that

```
# my_dag.py

from my_module import my_function


MY_VAR = 'Hello World'


with DAG(
    schedule_interval=my_function(),
    ...
): 
  ....
```

and then I have a test that imports from `my_dag`:

```
# test_my_dag.py

from my_dag import MY_VAR

...
```

---

Problem is that `my_function()` is supposed to initiate a connection, and thus, I would like to mock it since when importing `MY_VAR` in the test, will result in loading the DAG `my_dag.py` file, that will in turn run unmocked version of `my_function`.

How can I potentially mock `my_function` before importing from `my_dag` in tests?

Answer (score 0):

Use local import from test function

```
def test1(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('my_module.my_function', lambda : 'monkey business')
    from my_dag import MY_VAR
    ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The error appears when importing `from my_dag import MY_VAR
` in the test file, not when running the test and the way the code and tests are structured, local import won't work. For example, `MY_VAR` is used in test parametrization

Comment: You may also consider creating a conftest.py file with a function that mocks my_function. Eg:

```
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def mockmyfunction(monkeypatch):
        ...
```
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/fixtures.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files

Comment: Can you please update your answer and provide a specific example?

Comment: Actually it wont work with the conftest.py I don't see a way to avoid local import

Answer (score 0):

I am more used to `unittest` so I will give my solution using this package instead of `pytest`. How I reproduced your problem:

```
# my_module.py

def my_function():
    return "This is not mocked"
```

`my_dag.py` looks like this:

```
# my_dag.py

from my_module import my_function

MY_VAR = "Hello World"

print(my_function())
```

And `test_my_dag.py` looks like this:

```
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch('my_module.my_function', return_value="This is mocked") as mock_method:
    from my_dag import MY_VAR

class TestMyDag(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_my_var(self):
        self.assertEqual(MY_VAR, "Hello World")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The output of `test_my_dag.py` is:

```
This is mocked
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

To be honest, I don't know if this might be the best solution, but I hope this helps you dude.